# Mysql join two tables multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get two user_name and company name from the same two tables one is

```
gamer_user where u.id  = gamer_rec t2.user_id
```

where gamer_user has user_name, and gamer_rec has company name

```
SELECT t1.company,usc.`name`,ur.id,u.id,t1.user_name,t2.user_name
FROM `game_social` AS usc 
JOIN gamer_rec t2 ON t2.user_id = `usc`.`user_id` 
JOIN gamer_rec t1 ON t1.user_id = `u`.`id` 
JOIN `gamer_user` AS u ON `usc`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`  
JOIN `gamer_user` AS ur ON `ur`.`email` = `usc`.`email`
```

but i am getting error as

> [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'

**gamer_rec t1 or t2**

```
user_id user_name
1          paul
2          thomas
3          Nancy
```

**gamer_user u or ur**

```
id    user_id  email
1      2       eabce@abce.com
2      1       aabc@abc.com
3      4       dabcd@abcd.com
```

**game_social**

```
id  user_id   email
1    2       aabc@abc.com
2    3       dabcd@abcd.com
3    1       eabce@abce.com
4    6       fabcf@abcf.com
```

Here is the output.. please find t1.user_id and t2.user_id --- but i need `t2.user_id = ur.id and t1.user_id= u.id` are same

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join a table before you can use it. So switch the joins:

```sql
SELECT t1.company, t1.user_name, 
       t2.user_name,
       usc.`name`,
       ur.id, 
       u.id

FROM game_social usc 

JOIN gamer_user u ON `usc`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
JOIN gamer_user ur ON `ur`.`email` = `usc`.`email`

JOIN gamer_rec t1 ON t1.user_id = `u`.`id` 
JOIN gamer_rec t2 ON t2.user_id = `usc`.`user_id`
```

Comment: @Revamp the best way to say 'thank you' on SO is to accept the answer ;)

Comment: @RadimBača i did.. but it said u need to wait for 5 minutes...

Comment: @Revamp fine :)

Comment: @juergen a i am getting wrong values..i am getting t1.user_name and t2.user_name the same

Comment: Hard to tell without example data and expected output. I can't see what you really join and if it is correct. It would be interesting to see wat columns the `game_social` table has since you join on EMAIL and on USER_ID which is strange

Comment: JOIN gamer_user u ON `usc`.`user_id` = `ur`.`id`
JOIN gamer_user ur ON `ur`.`email` = `usc`.`email`

JOIN gamer_rec t1 ON t1.user_id = `ur`.`id` 
JOIN gamer_rec t2 ON t2.user_id = `usc`.`user_id` 
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'ur.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @Revamp: There is no table that contains a GAME_ID with multiple USER_IDs. So why join the same tables anyway? Does not make sense.

Comment: @juergend sorry there will be multiple game_id or user_id in game_social...  i get unique `u.id ` and  `ur.id ` from the query above but i cant use the  `ur.id ` in the  `join query `

Comment: @juergend sorry there will be multiple game_id or user_id in game_social...  i get unique `u.id ` and  `ur.id ` from the query above but i cant use the  `ur.id ` in the  `join query `

Comment: I will have a last look if you update your question to see all the columns and data necessary.